# bash, find order of focused windows (similar to the alt+tab menu)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, window, focus

High level, I'm trying to create a utility where I can map certain keys to focus the most recently focused window of a certain name.

E.g., pressing sup+c will focus chrome; if no chrome windows are open, it will create a new chrome window; if multiple chrome windows are open, it will focus the most recently focused one. Similarly, sup+t may do the same for terminal, etc.

I can use `xdotool search --name <window-name>` to find the window id's of a certain name. I can follow with `xdotool windowactivate <id>` to focus that window.

However, `xdotool search` returns all id's of matching windows; whereas I want to find the last focused matching window.

1) Is there a way to sort this by last-focused?

2) Or perhaps a way to fetch all windows by last-focus and then I can compare that list with the id's returned by `xdotool search`?

3) Or perhaps a way to have a callback called whenever window focus changes so that I can manually keep track of windows ordered by last-focus?

4) Any other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally found out, it seems `xdotool search` is already ordered starting with the oldest-focused windows (top) to the most recently focused (bottom).

If you open 4 terminal windows, and print their ids using `xdotool getactivewindow`, then in one type `xdotool search --name terminal`, their id's are printed in the order described above.

Edit: apparently this is not always the case. While this has worked for me for the last few days, I've noticed Chrome windows will be listed above other windows regardless of the focus order.

Comment: I think that everytime you open a new progam, that program will get a new PID (Process Id), and the PID is incremented for every program you open. Maybe it is sorting it by the PID?